# Fix Extremely low exposure pictures/videos

Tags: video, image-processing

I have got a shot of our successful performance, but we were shocked at how noisy and how low the exposure of the video is. It is hard for us to re-shot for some reason. So I plan to recover it, but from the [screencast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsbEG.png) in Blender you can see the situation, I tried to adjust Curves but it will go much more noisy and Sharp do not help very much. So is there any other image process methods can I do to recover it?

Lastly, I am not sure if it is suitable to post the question on this site, if not, please point out. I will appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: If it is underexposed, it has by definition a low dynamic range. Spreading this range by software to a normal viewing range also amplifies any noise. There is software for de-noising for photos (like LightRoom), so I am sure it exists for video too. The result will never be a great video, though. I don’t know any software, sorry.

Comment: You might post it to https://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Aganju I export it to TIFF sequences and import to Darktable, I adjust it (mainly shadows and highlights, I think it is related to dynamic range) and it is much brighter, but on the curtain, it is still full of noises regardless of denoise and details lost. Is there any tech 'guess' out the lost info? [screencast of Darktable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsbEG.png)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik In my view the mainly problem turns out to be the lost information caused by low exposure, but photo.stackexchange seems to discuss how to made beautiful pictures for artists. Anyway, I think my question is really hard to classify.

Comment: What I am mostly seeing in the dark areas is color noise. I don’t know the tools you use; in LigthRoom there is a _Color Noise_ slider which very efficiently removes this.

Comment: See https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfORM.jpg for a quick example (this is made from your posted shot). You probably can do slightly better, but that's about the limit - there is just not more information in the picture.

Comment: @Aganju I found a software called `neat image` it seems to make better effects than Darktable and works on Linux. Thanks for your guide.